# What is the "Intel Turbo Boost Technology Driver" for?

Tags: intel-core-i5, turbo-boost

What is the purpose of the *Intel Turbo Boost Technology Driver*?

It doesn't seem to be necessary for Turbo Boost to work properly, so what does it do?

Comment: Is it called "Intel Turbo Boost Technology Driver" or the "Intel(R) Turbo Boost Technology Monitor 2.0"?

Comment: @WilliamHilsum: [**Driver**](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCCW27FXB&upd_id=5284&os_group_id=6)

Comment: Newer I series processors do not need the TB driver, its built into the processor now.

Comment: @Moab: Huh... which processors does that series include? (By "I series" do you mean the i3/i5/i7 series, or just a subset of them?)

Comment: Second Gen I series, i7 for sure. I see lots of complaints on second gen when trying to install the TB driver, it won't install because it does not need one, see post by Joe G...http://communities.intel.com/thread/11604

Comment: @Moab: Hmmmmm okay... though it *does* install; it's just not needed apparently, that's all.

Comment: Having this enabled is causing high fan usage when the PC is idle. When I log in, the fan slows and is quiet again. Weird. Since it doesn't need a driver installed any more I guess it's working as intended but don't really know. I'm just going to disable it in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the Intel Turbo Boost Technology Driver is described on the [FAQ page of the driver](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000021587.html):

> **What is Intel® Turbo Boost Max Technology 3.0 and how does it work?**
>
> Intel® Turbo Boost Max Technology 3.0 uses a driver coupled with
>   information stored in the CPU to identify and direct workloads to the
>   fastest core on the die first. The driver also allows for custom
>   configuration via a whitelist that enables end users to set priority
>   to preferred applications. The driver MUST be present on the system
>   and configured correctly, as current operating systems cannot
>   effectively route workloads to ordered cores.